# Text string array to array in java

Tags: java, arrays

i have problem with my JSON response, i dont know how conwert this string:

> ["Lorem ipsum1","Lorem ipsum2","Lorem ipsum3"]

to array in java.
This text is result of `JSONObject.getString("message");`.

I was thinking of using `split();` but could not set the appropriate attributes

Thanks for help! I use:`JSONObject.getJSONArray("message");`
and convert it to array using this:

> `public static String[] getStringArray(JSONArray jsonArray){
>           String[] stringArray = null;
>           int length = jsonArray.length();
>           if(jsonArray!=null){
>               stringArray = new String[length];
>               for(int i=0;i<length;i++){
>                   stringArray[i]= jsonArray.optString(i);
>               }
>           }
>           return stringArray;
>       }`

Comment: The JSON you posted is an array, why are you retrieving it as a string?

Comment: https://google.com/search?q=java+json+parser

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I am not sure, if i understand you correctly, but what about JSONObject.getJSONArray("message")?